# Ruby - A request route with a wildcard doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Could someone suggest why these 2 routes aren't the same:

`get('/:id/' => 'outlets/play#show', :as => :listen, constraints: { id: /thetrack-a123-bay7623/ } )`

`get('/:id/' => 'outlets/play#show', :as => :listen, constraints: { id: /thetrack-.*/ } )`

What I'm trying to achieve is only want that route `outlets/play#show` to be used when there is an `:id` that begins with `thetrack`.

I've found that if I explicitly use those characters its fine i.e. without `thetrack` in the route it doesnt use that route. However if I use `thetrack-.*` it still goes into the `outlets/play#show` route despite `thetrack` not being present in my request.

Any ideas?

I've tried other regex patterns e.g.
`thetrack-.+`
`thetrack-.+-.+`
`thetrack-.*-.*`
with no luck

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is route any request `/:id/` with ID starting with `thetrack-` to `outlets/play#show`, then your configured route should work:

```
get '/:id/', to: 'outlets/play#show', as: :listen, constraints: { id: /thetrack-.*/ }
```

Here are some example paths that will route to `outlets/play#show` using this wildcard:

- `/thetrack-`
- `/thetrack-a123`
- `/thetrack-a123-bay7623`

`/:id/` is quite broad reaching. Check that you have not got any other conflicting routes. i.e. another route at root level `/:something/` that could be catching the other requests where `thetrack-` is not specified.